# GWT: tap/click on iPad Safari last too long

Tags: gwt

I have an small situation. When I tap some areas of the screen a Form with TextItems is meant to popup and the first one is meant to receive focus.

The problem is that even after poping up the window, the iPad is acting like if I'm still clicking, resulting on a click on whatever is in that X,Y position onto the pop up screen. I can see the iPad keyboard poping up and hiding immediately because of that.

Does someone have any past experiences with issues like this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple technique is to set a small timer when the view loads, say 500ms,  then set the focus field in the timer handler.  It isn't an elegant solution to the problem, but it is hard to debounce a touch in user level code.